# expressJs reverse proxy not working

Tags: python, node.js, express, reverse-proxy

Have an appA running on localhost:8000 -> server is python(Django) and always crashes
I have an expressJs server running on localhost:8080
I am appA's static files for the expressJs server and it works well.

Problem: I want to create a reverse proxy in expressJs **so that I can forward any incoming api request to the express server**. **Basically, the app should work with the new expressJs server (just like it used to with the Django/python server)**

Here's what I have. But it doesn't work. When try to hit an endpoint in localhost:8000 form localhost:8080 (such as localhost:8080/api/my-profile), I get an error.

**forward.js:**

```
var request = require('request')

module.exports = function(pattern, host){
  return function(req, res, next){
    if(req.url.match(pattern)){
      var db_path = req.url.match(pattern)[1]
        , db_url = [host, db_path].join('/');
      req.pipe(request[req.method.toLowerCase()](db_url)).pipe(res);
    }else{
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

**app.js:**

```
var forward = require('./path/to/forward.js');

// instantiate `app` et al

app.use(forward(/\/api\/(.*)/, TARGET_URL));

app.listen(8080);
```

The regex catches any request starting with /api/, and catches anything following that prefix so we can forward it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say exactly what the issue is without more details on the error that you're seeing. The good news is that other people have already solved this issue. I have had good luck with a module called `proxy-middleware`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-middleware

In your case I think you could get rid of `forward.js` and modify your `app.js`:

```
var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
var url = require('url');

// instantiate `app` et al

app.use(proxy('/api', url.parse(TARGET_URL)));

app.listen(8080);
```